# Using Scanner...Error: '.class' expected

Tags: java

getDiscountedBill() will return final amount of the bill
if the bill is >2000, the bill receives a 15% discount

```
public class Discount
{
private double bill;
private double discount;
private double amt;

public static double getDiscountedBill(double bill)
{
    if (bill > 2000)
    {
        discount = bill * .15; 
        amt = bill - discount; 
    }

    return amt;

    if (bill <= 2000)
    {
        return bill;
    }
}

public void print()
{
    System.out.println("Bill after discount :: ");
    System.out.printf("%.2f\n", amt);
}
```

code in another main

```
    public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    out.print("Enter the original bill amount :: ");
    double amt = keyboard.nextDouble();

    keyboard.getDiscountedBill(double);
    keyboard.print();
```

error message:error: '.class' expected
        keyboard.getDiscountedBill(double);

Comment: What do you think you are doing with this code? `keyboard.getDiscountedBill(double);` What are you passing to the method?

Comment: What do you think `keyboard.getDiscountedBill(double);` does?

Answer (score 2):

Change this statement:

```
keyboard.getDiscountedBill(double);
```

with this one:

```
double discuontedBill = getDiscountedBill(amt);
```

You're supposed to **pass a value** as a method argument, not to **pass a type** .